# Running batches of concurrent tasks with asyncio

Tags: concurrency, python-asyncio

I don't understand how to use asyncio to run concurrent tasks in batches.
Below is a minimal working example of what I'm trying to do: A main function which consumes batch of items and writes them. Each batch can be processed sequentially, but within each batch, (slow I/O bound) tasks should be running concurrently.

It runs, but tasks are never executed concurrently and I do not understand why.

```py
import asyncio
import random
import time

async def process_single(item: str) -> str:
    """Slow I/O function to process a single element"""
    print(f"started: {item}")
    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 5))  # Simulating I/O-bound processing
    print(f"processed: {item}")
    return f"returned {item}"

async def process_batch(batch: list[str]) -> list[str]:
    """Executes a slow I/O bound function asynchronously on a batch of samples"""
    results = []
    for item in batch:
        result = await process_single(item)
        results.append(result)
    return results

def write_results(results: list[str]):
    print(results)

async def main():
    batches = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]

    for batch in batches:
        results = await process_batch(batch)
        write_results(results)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Here is the output, task `n+1` always starts after task `n` has finished. What am I doing wrong?

```
started: a
processed: a
started: b
processed: b
started: c
processed: c
['returned a', 'returned b', 'returned c']
started: d
processed: d
started: e
processed: e
started: f
processed: f
['returned d', 'returned e', 'returned f']
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears I should have used `asyncio.gather` for this, and used `await async.sleep` instead of `time.sleep`. The following works as expected:

```py
import asyncio
import random
import time

async def process_single(item: str) -> str:
    """Slow I/O function to process a single element"""
    print(f"started: {item}")
    await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(1, 5))  # Simulating I/O-bound processing using asyncio.sleep
    print(f"processed: {item}")
    return f"returned {item}"

async def process_batch(batch: list[str]) -> list[str]:
    """Executes a slow I/O bound function asynchronously on a batch of samples"""
    tasks = [process_single(item) for item in batch]
    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return results

def write_results(results: list[str]):
    print(results)

async def main():
    batches = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]

    for batch in batches:
        results = await process_batch(batch)
        write_results(results)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```